# May local role be inherited in Plone?

Tags: plone, roles

I had created folder1 in Plone site root and add local role "manager" for user adam to folder1,next I had created document1 in folder1. I want to know if user adam has a local "manager" role for document1.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, by default, permissions from the container of a document are inherited, except if you manually disable this behavior in the document's sharing tab.

[image: Plone sharing tab]
[image: Plone sharing tab - inherit permission from higher levels]